# Tappable area of an Image Button in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to dismiss my current view on the tap of an image but the tappable area of that image is bigger than the actual image (Blue background is also tappable as shown in the image), if I increase the image size the tappable area also increases, How can I remove the blue box around the image but still be able to increase image size?

```
 Image("Cancel")
      .resizable()
      .scaledToFit()
      .contentShape(Circle())
      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

      .background(Color.blue)
      .onTapGesture {
      presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
      }
```

[Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Lg8.png)

Comment: SwiftPunk's answer is correct but I just copy-pasted what Paul Hudson taught in the course and it's absolutely perfect also it makes the surrounding frame the same size as of image

Image("Cancel")
.renderingMode(.original)
.clipShape(Circle())
.overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black,lineWidth: 1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use clipShape like in code:

---

### [image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .contentShape(Circle())
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .onTapGesture {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        
    }
}
```